# convert hued displot of X to plot of hue vs mode(X given hue)?

Tags: seaborn

I have a Seaborn displot with a hued variable:

[image]

For each hued variable, I want to extract the mode of the density estimate and then plot each hue variable versus its mode, like so:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scipy.stats.gaussian_kde to create the density estimation function. And then call that function on an array of x-values to calculate its maximum.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.normal(0.001, 1, 1300).cumsum() + 30,
                   'hue': np.repeat(np.arange(0.08, 0.20001, 0.01), 100).round(2)})
g = sns.displot(df, x='x', hue='hue', palette='turbo', kind='kde', fill=True, height=6, aspect=1.5)
plt.show()

from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
hues = df['hue'].unique()
num_hues = len(hues)
colors = sns.color_palette('turbo', num_hues)
xmin, xmax = df['x'].min(), df['x'].max()
xs = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 500)
for hue, color in zip(hues, colors):
     data = df[df['hue'] == hue]['x'].values
     kde = gaussian_kde(data)
     mode_index = np.argmax(kde(xs))
     mode_x = xs[mode_index]
     sns.scatterplot(x=[hue], y=[mode_x], color=color, s=50, ax=ax)
cmap = sns.color_palette('turbo', as_cmap=True)
norm = plt.Normalize(hues.min(), hues.max())
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), ax=ax, ticks=hues)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot with hue]

[image: scatterplot with the modes]

Here is another approach, extracting the kde curves. It uses the legend of the kde plot to get the correspondence between the curves and the hue values.  `sns.kdeplot` is the axes-level function used by `sns.displot(kind='kde')`. `fill=False` creates lines instead of filled polygons for the curves, for which the values are easier to extract. (`ax1.fill_between` can fill the curves during a second pass). The x and y axes of the second plot are switched to align the x-axes of both plots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.normal(0.007, 0.1, 1300).cumsum() + 30,
                   'hue': np.repeat(np.arange(0.08, 0.20001, 0.01), 100).round(2)})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=True)

sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='x', hue='hue', palette='turbo', fill=False, ax=ax1)

hues = [float(txt.get_text()) for txt in ax1.legend_.get_texts()]
ax2.set_yticks(hues)
ax2.set_ylabel('hue')
for hue, line in zip(hues, ax1.lines[::-1]):
     color = line.get_color()
     x = line.get_xdata()
     y = line.get_ydata()
     ax1.fill_between(x, y, color=color, alpha=0.3)
     mode_ind = np.argmax(y)
     mode_x = x[mode_ind]
     sns.scatterplot(x=[mode_x], y=hue, color=color, s=50, ax=ax2)

sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: calculating the mode from the kde curves]

Comment: I was hoping to find a way that extracts the KDE information from the sns.displot. Is that possible?

Comment: You can indeed extract the points of the curves, but it would be more error prone to know which hue value would correspond to which curve. The code would become more complicated without any extra benefit.

Comment: My concern with this approach is that the data displayed in the first plot and the data displayed in the second plot are computed separately. That raises the spectre of a possible discrepancy

Comment: In that case, you could use the data of the second plot to recreate the first. I also added an approach to directly calculate the modes from the curves.

Comment: Oops. The lines are in the reversed order as the legend. I updated the code (using `ax1.lines[::-1]`)